# Is there a typescript definition for window?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a javascript function that I am trying to convert to typescript.  Here's a part of the function:

```
// needs Markdown.Converter.js at the moment

(function () {

    var util = {},
        position = {},
        ui = {},
        doc = window.document,
        re = window.RegExp,
```

I am getting an error telling me that: The property RegExp does not exist on type Window.  Is there any kind of definition file that I could include for window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try passing global arguments to the anonymous block:

```js
(function(window, document) {
  var re = window.RegExp;
  console.log(re);
})(window, document);
```

```html
Open console...
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Works perfectly. I will accept in 7 mins.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, you don't need to use `window` for `RegExp` and in fact its *bad practice* because you are converting your JS Environment (Node.js / Browser) independent code to Browser specific code for no reason. Its like using `global.RegExp` in node.js when you clearly don't need to use `global`. I would do :

```
// needs Markdown.Converter.js at the moment

(function () {
    var util = {},
        position = {},
        ui = {},
        doc = window.document,
        re = RegExp; // No error
})();
```